# syntax error using selectedMeasure() and filter in DAX

Tags: dax

anyboady can help me to solve this issue?

```
CALCULATE( 
  SELECTEDMEASURE (), 
  filter(DimDate,DimDate[MonthNumberOfYear] = max(DimDate[MonthNumberOfYear]))
)
```

DAX Editor has Syntax ERROR

Comment: You have an extra ```)``` at the end of the ```filter``` line

Answer (score 0):

Functions like

1. SELECTEDMEASURE
2. ISSELECTEDMEASURE
3. SELECTEDMEASUREFORMATSTRING, and
4. SELECTEDMEASURENAME

can only be used inside a Calculation Item in a Calculation Group which can only be crated using Tabular Editor. You will have to refer to the explicit measure inside CALCULATE.